# static NSMutableArray *words[10] incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c, static, nsmutablearray

`static NSMutableArray *words[10]= {@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",nil};`

gives warning:
"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'

How should I circumvent this problem?

Comment: An NSMutableArray is a single object which is an array. You are trying to declare an array of NSMutableArrays. Most likely that's not what you wanted. You are then trying to initialise the individual mutable arrays, each with an NSString*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not compile even without static

1.Remove [10]

2.Change '{...}' to '@[...]'

3.Remove `nil`

You should receive

```
NSMutableArray *words= @[@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word"];
```

but `words` will be a NSArray, not NSMutableArray since it is initializated with NSArray object. And if you will try to declare it `static' you will receive a compiler error

> initializer element is not a compile-time constant

because only compile-time constant could be declared as `static`. NSMutableArray could not be created at compile time.

If you need static array you should use C-style array instead

```
static NSString *words[] = {@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word",@"word"};
```

Comment: Just to note that the first one will be _not_ a mutable array (even if declared so)